# Get Internet Explorer security settings from end user

Tags: security, internet-explorer

There are reported problems with our web application which only seem to be happening at one client's site. For diagnostic purposes, is there any way you can get a client to send you their IE Security custom settings ? e.g. In IE 8, Tools -> Internet Options -> Security Tab, for the "Internet" zone, you can click "Custom Level" to see the custom security settings. Is there some way the user can export their settings to a text file or something ? Or are screen dumps the only way ?

EDIT : sorry, should have mentioned it is for Windows XP (SP3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`gpedit.msc -> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer`

Right click, `Export List...`

Comment: In Windows XP The "Internet Explorer" node doesn't seem to exist ? Sorry, I should have been more specific.

Comment: Not sure since I'm not XP, but try "Right click on Administrative Templates, and then click Add/Remove
Templates and add the inetres template (inetres.adm). You should find
the template in %systemroot%\system32\GroupPolicy\Adm. " from http://www.technologyquestions.com/technology/windows-xp/380781-gpedit-msc-doesnt-show-internet-explorer-options.html

Comment: Can you dump the list recursively?  It looks like there are a lot of subfolders that don't get included in the dump.

Answer (score 1):

If your user is using Windows 7, you might want to try the "record steps to reproduce a problem" built into windows 7 (possibly vista too, I'm not sure).  It takes screenshots and gives you some basic statistics.

Just have them type in  "record steps to reproduce a problem" in the "search for programs and files" text box under the windows 7 equivalent of the start button.