# How to grab a snapshot/dump of IE9 security settings?

Tags: security, debugging, internet-explorer-9

Trying to investigate an issue a customer is facing where he gets a generic IE9 error - "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". We have ruled out connection settings as a potential cause, is there any to get a dump/snapshot of the security settings on this customer's computer?

I already saw some threads on the forum regarding gpedit.msc ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940853/get-internet-explorer-security-settings-from-end-user)); however when I did a dry run on my system I am not seeing the information that I expect. I.e. the operation is not recursive and the few sites in my trusted/blocked list do not show up either. Is there a better method?

Vin

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4940853/get-internet-explorer-security-settings-from-end-user